# Recursive directory processing in a BAT file with a twist

Tags: windows, recursion, batch-file, directory

OK, I apologize ahead of time for a) using an old, crappy technology (BAT files) and b) asking what seems to be a redundant question. I'm limited in the technology I'm allowed to use in this particular case and after looking at dozens of posts on the subject I can't find anything I can adapt to what I need.

I have a directory structure that looks like this:
A
  B
    C
      D
        etc...
          XYZ
            more folders

My BAT file is located outside this files system. I need to inspect it starting at level "C" and need to find the "XYZ" directory. The folders between C and XYZ can have variable names depending on the environment in which the files were created.  I need to end up with a string that consists of the directory names from C through XYZ (i.e. "C\D\E\F....\XYZ") that I can put into a variable so when my BAT file is completed I can reference the variable and run another command.

I've looked at posts using FIND and FOR but I can't seem to figure out how to a) limit the string to the starting directory (for example when I combine FOR with DIR I get "A\B\C...") and how to stop when I get to "XYZ"...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "old, crappy"? Agree but still useful and very lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in most situations:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "root=c:\a\b\c"
set "target=xyz"

for %%R in ("%root%") do for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s /ad "%root%\%target%"'
) do (
  set "fullPath=%%F"
  set "relpath=!fullPath:%%~dpR=!"
)
echo !relpath!
```

It can fail if any of your paths contain `!` or `=`. There are solutions for this, but the code is significantly more complicated.

**EDIT**

Actually, there is a relatively simple solution using FORFILES that should work in all situations. (Assuming your version of Windows has FORFILES)

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "root=c:\a\b\c"
set "target=xyz"

for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'forfiles /p "%root%" /m "%target%" /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @relpath"'
) do set "relpath=%%~F"
for %%R in ("%root%") do set "relpath=%%~nxR%relpath:~1%"
echo %relpath%
```

The only restriction is the code has to change slightly if your result contains poison characters like `&`. In that case you need to add quotes to the final ECHO statement, or else enable delayed expansion at the end and use `echo !relpath!`

Comment: How do I access fullPath outside the scope of the For command? This is the issue I always run into trying to use delayed expansion. Once I find the fullPath I need to use it in subsequent code in the same BAT file?

Comment: EDIT - I simplified my first solution, and modified it to set a variable

Comment: This runs perfectly from my local PC. I pushed it to the web server where it needs to run and I get a "The specified directory does not exist." error on the first FOR command. Probably something dumb I did when pushing it to the server. Thanks.

Comment: OMG - When I read your question, it looks to me like you want the relative path: a string like "C\D\E\F....\XYZ". Getting the full path is trivial.

Comment: The edited version DOES get the relative path, not the full path. That is what I need. The only thing I have to adjust is that if my root is A\B\C I don't want my relative path to start with "C", it should be "D\E\F...XYZ". I SHOULD be able to figure that out.

Comment: Changed "relpath=%%~nxR%relpath:~1%" to "relpath=%relpath:~2%" and I have exactly what I need. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For a) question:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%d IN ('DIR A\B\C\XYZ /S /AD /B') DO SET variable=%%d
```

For a) and b) question:

```
FOR /D /R "A\B\C" %%d IN (*.*) DO IF /I "%%~nxd"=="XYZ" (SET variable=%%d& GOTO :EOF)
```

but this will exit batch script, so you need:

```
... your batch code
CALL :GET_XYZ
... your batch code
GOTO :EOF

:GET_XYZ
FOR /D /R "A\B\C" %%d IN (*.*) DO IF /I "%%~nxd"=="XYZ" (SET variable=%%d& GOTO :EOF)
ECHO XYZ not found!
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: All code above includes A\B\C\... in output, but OP wants the output to start with C\...